# Group intersecting/overlapping com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon

Tags: postgis, java, intersection, jts-topology-suite, st-intersects

I have list of `geometry` type in a database or:

```
List<com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon> polygons
```

Is there any JTS Topology Suite method or PostGIS function which would output intersecting groups as unions of `Polygon`?

For example, if I provide list of polygons(boxes) like below, I would expect to get list of unions: one made of 1, 2, 10 boxes, another of 5,7, etc.

[image]

Comment: Are the boxes numbered as 1, 2, 3... the envelopes of the MultiPoints?

Comment: I would expect output - list of unions - one made of 1-2-10 boxes, another of 4-9-8 and so forth.

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: Boxes are different MultiPoint objects.

Comment: They can't be. MultiPoints are collections of one or more points but you are showing rectangles. I suppose that they are bounding boxes which enclose the MultiPoints because nothing else makes sense but I hope that you can confirm.

Comment: Maybe com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon makes sense? I may use incorrect class.

Comment: Please try to analyze your case and formulate it then as an understandable question.

Comment: Reformulated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found PostGIS function which solves the problem:

> [ST_ClusterIntersecting](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterIntersecting.html) — Aggregate. Returns an array with the
>   connected components of a set of geometries
>
> ST_ClusterIntersecting is an aggregate function that returns an array
>   of GeometryCollections, where each GeometryCollection represents an
>   interconnected set of geometries.